# KnockoutJS extender does not formats second time with the same value

Tags: knockout.js

I use the following extender:

```
var toMoney = function (val, decimals) {
    return Number(val).toFixed(decimals).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1\'');
};

function formatToNumber(str, decimals) {
    var roundingMultiplier = Math.pow(10, decimals);

    //Strip out everything except numbers and decimals (also strip out '%' and 'R')
    var newValueAsNum = new String(str).replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
    if (isNaN(newValueAsNum)) {
        //can happen with two decimals.
        newValueAsNum = 0;
    }
    var valueToWrite = Math.round(newValueAsNum * roundingMultiplier) / roundingMultiplier;

    return valueToWrite;
}

//Add formatted observable to the target observable.
ko.extenders.addCurrencyFormatted = function (target, decimals) {
    target.formatted = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            var val = target();

            //Insert 1000 space.
            if (val != null) {
                var formattedValue = toMoney(val, decimals);
                return formattedValue;
            }
            return "";
        },
        write: function (newValue) {
            var current = target();
            var valueToWrite = formatToNumber(newValue, decimals);

            //only write if it changed
            if (valueToWrite !== current) {
                target(valueToWrite);
            } else {
            if (valueToWrite === current) {
                if (newValue !== current) {
                    target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return target;
};
```

If I write into the input 1000, it formats to 1'000.00. But the if I write 1000 again, it leaves so. What do I wrong?

I got the code from this [source](https://gist.github.com/willemodendaal/9976190), and there is also a jsfiddle link in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the computed observable target.formatted didn't change, and if it doesn't change, KO doesn't update the linked input.

The solution is to add the following extender to  target.formatted:

.extend({notify: 'always'});

This forces KO to think that target.formatted has a new value, and therefore will overwrite your input with the formatted input.